# If I get a laptop with Windows 10, is there anything I should know about installing Linux besides disabling Secure Boot under Windows?

Tags: windows-10, installation, linux-mint, vmware, secure-boot

### If I get a laptop with Windows 10 and Secure Boot, and I disable Secure Boot, is there anything I should know about installing Linux besides the process used with BIOS?

I am expecting a laptop with Windows 10 on the hard drive, and want to disable Secure Boot, keep Windows 10 on the primary hard drive, install Linux Mint on a secondary hard drive, and have GRUB let the user choose to run Windows or Linux.

Is there anything I should know about the installation besides needing to disable Secure Boot before any other installation? Or is a Secure Boot UEFI system that has had Secure Boot turned off basically like Linux installation under BIOS?

One specific aspect: if I want to use hardware virtualization under Linux and it is not enabled by default, is that something I enable in UEFI independently of Secure Boot, or where in the process should I enable hardware virtualization?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you disabling Secure Boot in order to install Linux?  Most Linux distributions actually support Secure Boot.  What does Hardware virtualization have to do with Secure Boot?

Comment: Linux Mint left the computer inoperative after an intended installation. Hence the question.

Comment: @Ramhound More specifically, I tried to install Mint, leaving the EFI partition alone. During the setup questions, Mint asked whether I wanted to install third-party software. I clicked "Yes," and I was asked for a password/passphrase to enable the next boot in lieu of Secure Boot, so it could install third-party software. Then I rebooted at the obvious time, and the computer wouldn't boot: it wouldn't boot by itself, and it wouldn't boot either on my live Mint USB. I was never prompted for the boot password I had specified. Hence my regarding Secure Boot as an impediment to installing Mint.

Comment: The only thing I know is that Mont absolutely does support [Secure Boot](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2191#linfse).  How you get Secure Boot working with Mint doesn’t seem within scope to the question you have asked.  I was only seeking clarification on the reason you believed it was necessary to disable it.  Secure Boot is not required for any version of Windows that runs on x86 hardware.  Microsoft has a requirement on all OEM vendors which requires a method to disable Secure Boot.  Secure Boot != UEFI; UEFI mode is required to boot GPT (Windows).

Comment: The link you provided says, "The installation require: PC with firmware UEFI and Secure Boot disabled, HDD with GPT partitioning scheme."

Comment: I erroneously read the description incorrectly of that particular section.  I suspect the only reason Secure Boot is required is due to the use of FDE.  [How to enable UEFI Secure Boot with your own Custom keys on PC with UEFI & HDD with GPT](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2360) is the correct section.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Linux distros, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or later, do **not** require turning off Secure Boot. However:

- In BIOS/UEFI, [turn off Fast Boot](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?37800-Hardware-fast-boot-under-the-Boot-menu-what-exactly-is-that) permanently.
- In BIOS, on some computers, you may need to enable legacy USB boot.
- In Windows, [turn off Fast Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) permanently, and [turn off Hibernate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running) before you plan to boot to Linux.

The reason for turning off the "fast" options above is that they leave the Windows partition "dirty", i.e. the various *.sys* files should not be touched, lest the computer not be able to reboot to Windows. Most Linux distros prevent write access to the Windows partition if dirty, and will not mount it for read access by default.

The following two scripts can be saved to batch files to quickly enable or disable Hibernate, respectively and to then shut down:

```
powercfg -h on
shutdown /h

powercfg -h off
shutdown /s /t 0
```